# The parameter 'chatmessage' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently using the [dash_chat](https://pub.dev/packages/dash_chat) package to implement chat functionality in my app, but facing this issue:

```
The parameter 'chatmessage' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'.
Try adding an explicit non-'null' default value.
```

My code looks like this:

```dart
messageImageBuilder: (url, [chatmessage]) => Container(
  height: 200,
  width: 200,
  child: PhotoView(
    imageProvider: NetworkImage(url!),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mention the parameter `chatmessage` with type `ChatMessage?`.

Your code should be like..

```
messageImageBuilder: (url, [ChatMessage? chatmessage]) => Container(
  height: 200,
  width: 200,
  child: PhotoView(
    imageProvider: NetworkImage(url!),
  ),
),
```